# Validity of a first order formula depends only on cardinality of domain?

Tags: model-theory, first-order-logic

In chapter 4, exercise 1 of Smullyan's First-Order Logic he asks for a proof to the question appearing on the title. His phraseology is this: Show that the validity or satisfiability of a formula in a universe U depends only on the cardinality of U.

This seems wrong on the face of it to me; I mean doesn't the internal structure of the domain matter? A formula claiming a least element is true in $\mathbb{N}_{<}$ but not true in $\mathbb{Z}_{<}$. I know I am shifting domains here and he is asking for U-validity, not unrestricted validity.

What is it that I am not seeing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

"... within a specific *universe* $\text U$", where $\text U$ is any non-empty set.

You have not to rely on the "intended" interpretation... Consider e.g. :

> $\exists x \forall y P^2xy$.

If we interpret $P$ as "less-equal" it is satisfied in $\mathbb N$ but not in $\mathbb Z$. But if we interpret $P$ as "less-than" is it false also in $\mathbb N$ [see similar *Example* page 48].

Conclusion : the above formula is not $\mathbb N$-valid.

---

Compare with $k$-validity, see :

- Geoffrey Hunter, [Metalogic : An Introduction to the Metatheory of Standard First Order Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=oHpMtskGcv0C&printsec=frontcover) (1971), pag 160-on.

Simple example of $1$-valid formula :

> $Px \to \forall x Px$.

By the way, the above formula is not $2$-valid, and thus it is not *valid*.

In order to show that the above formula is $1$-valid, we have no need to interpret the *predicate* symbol $P$; it is enough to consider a single-element universe $U= \{ a \}$.

Two cases : *(i)* $P(a)$ does not hold, and thus the formula is *true*. *(ii)* $P(a)$ holds, and thus also $\forall x Px$, and again the formula is *true*.

Comment: I understand nonlogical symbols can have different interpretations. Take the sentence ∀y∃xf(x) = y. Suppose the variables take real numbers as values and f is defined by the rule f(x) = x^2. Then the above sentence is false since there is no x such that f(x) = −1, say. If the function f is interpreted by f(x) = x^3 then the sentence is true. f is just looking to be one-to-one. As you can see, I did not shift the domain this time. I just fail to see how cardinality of the domain is the only relevant factor. Could you be more explicit in showing me how this is?

Comment: @CarlosTrebbau - perfect; you have showed that $∀y∃xf(x) = y$ is not $\mathbb R$-valid.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

$$
\exists x \exists y\ x \neq y.
$$

True in any model whose domain has cardinality greater than 1.  False in any model whose domain has cardinality 1.

The example is easily extended to all finite cardinalities.